# sql query to delete all attribute except primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, sql-delete

Suppose I have a database with 3 tables of rooms: room_lvl1, room_lvl2, room_lvl3 which represent 3 levels in a building. Each level has 20++ rooms. So each table of room has 20++ rows that represent the rooms in that level.

I have a need to delete all attributes in the table except the primary key which is the room number or update everything to a null value except the primary key.

Is there any query I could possibly run?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I'm not sure what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set values to `NULL` by doing:

```
update room_lvl1
    set col1 = NULL,
        col2 = NULL,
        . . .;
```

Where `col1` etc are the non-primary key columns.

That seems like a really strange thing to want to do.  You could empty the tables:

```
truncate table room_lvl1;
```

That would remove all rows.

You could save, truncate, and re-insert:

```
create table temp_room_lvl1 as select * from room_lvl1;

truncate table room_lvl1;

insert into room_lvl1(pk)
    select pk from temp_room_lvl1;
```